# Fragment it passed data but doesn't update the list adapter

Tags: android, list, android-fragments, adapter

I have two fragments on one `Activity`. When I click a button on **fragment A** , an object passes to **Fragment B** through an interface implementation in the `Activity` hosting them both. 
It does get to the **Fragment B** , but then the list doesn't get updated, it remains empty..

I've tried placing `notifyDataSetChanged()` in every possible way already..

**Fragment B:**

```
public class HistoryFragment extends ListFragment
 {

private static PasswordAdapter adapter ;
private static List<Password> historyList = new ArrayList<Password>();  

 //This is the object I get from Fragment A via the activity interface implementation
public static void addToData( Password addToList ) 
{ 
historyList.add( addToList );
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
historyList = Password.getTriedPasswords();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup   container, Bundle savedInstanceState)        { 

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);
adapter = new PasswordAdapter( historyList );
setListAdapter(adapter);
return view;
}

private class PasswordAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private ArrayList<Password> data; 

public PasswordAdapter( List<Password> historyList ) 
{
    data = new ArrayList<Password>();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    data.addAll( historyList );
}

@Override
public int getCount() 
{
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Password getItem( int position ) 
{
    return data.get( position );
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO implement you own logic with ID
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View result;

    if (convertView == null) 
    {
        result = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.history_list_item, parent, false);
    } 
    else 
    {
        result = convertView;
    }

    Password item = getItem( position );

    ( (TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.historyPasswordTextView) ).setText(item.getPasswordString());
    ( (TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.historyDateTextView) ).setText(item.getPasswordString());

    return result;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Why are you using a static list?

Comment: certain restraints.. for example the `public static void addToData(..)` would result in an error if the list wouldn't be static..

Comment: I think your menber functions and variables should not be static...

Comment: Well, that function shouldn't be static either...
In the enclosing activity, you should keep a reference to the instance of this fragment, or find it again using FragmentManager.

Comment: Thanks. Ok I've changed that.. Unfortunately though it still doesn't solve the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding an item to your list your adapter is not notified.
Try doing this in your fragment

```
public void addToData( Password addToList ) 
{       
     historyList.add(addToList);
     adapter.updateList(historyList);
}
```

In your adapter you create a new method

```
public void updateList(ArrayList<Password> newData){
    data.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < newData.size(); i++){
        data.add(newData.get(i));
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer, can you check if this works for you?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!
I've been on this for two days straight!
Works like a charm :)